# How to delete a notification from a game request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to delete an application notification on application load.
So when I invite my friend he gets a notification and requests "ok" and if he clicks on it then it should be deleted. How? I have tried multiple ways but haven't succeeded.

```
$REQIDs=$_REQUEST['request_ids'];
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXX&grant_type=client_credentials";
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
if($REQIDs){
$requests = explode(',',$REQIDs);
foreach($requests as $request_id){
$deleted = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$request_id?$access_token&method=delete");
//not working ->> {"error":{"type":"GraphMethodException","message":"Unsupported delete request."}}
$deleted = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_profile['id']."_".$request_id."?".$access_token);
//not working ->> false
$deleted = $facebook->api($request_id."?".$access_token, "DELETE");
//not working ->> Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported delete request.
}
}
```

Anyone have some ideas or see the error?

Comment: The error that you are getting in the first method you tried, namely
{"error":{"type":"GraphMethodException","message":"Unsupported delete request."}}
can only be caused by sending wrong request_id, so do recheck that you are sending only 1 request id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this topic here >>> [Topic](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=88364). It explains pretty fully how to handle apprequests.

Your code should look like this:

```
$reqId = $_GET['request_ids']; // Get the id of the current request
$requests = $facebook->api('/me/apprequests/?request_ids='.$reqId);  //Get the request. Not sure if this is correct for specific request
$itemData = $requests[data][0][data];  //Get the data that was originally sent in the request

//Some code here to do whatever with the data

$delete_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$reqId."?access_token=".$token."&method=delete";

$result = file_get_contents($delete_url);  //Delete the request so there is only one there next time.
```

This is supposed to do the work.

Good luck!

Comment: if i do like this i get "{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Invalid OAuth access token signature."}}" because $access_token is allredy containing "access_token="

Comment: graph returns access_token=xxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will pass you the request ids when your user clicks through. You can then make a call to this url to delete the request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[request_ids]?access_token=[your_app_accessToken]&method=delete
```

Note that if your application has sent a few requests to a single user, when they click the Notification Jewel in their FB header menu, your code will be sent all request ids in a comma separated string. You will need to code around this fact. I think I'm right in saying that the order of the ids in this string is oldest -> newest so to delete the most recent, you need to parse out the last id in the string and delete it.

Comment: i know there can be multiple id's thats not problem problem is i get error and i dont understand why and how facebook have this working is all messed up somehow... i get "{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Invalid OAuth access token signature."}}"

Comment: You will need to retrieve an application access token in order to make the delete call work. When ever you see the error message you are seeing, it means you either don't have an access_token at all, don't have the correct one (app or user) or don't have a valid one.

You can get an app access_token by sending a POST to this URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials